# Parameters bypassing when a "ser" is entered rather than a number

Tags: python

I have a function that I need to return back with the original question if there is text input rather than the number in the range given.

When I type in SER for instance to test the program it comes back with an error. I need a number to be input which relates to a given piece of code based on that number. How can I alter this?

```
def Choice(question):
  choiceanswer=input(question)
  if choiceanswer in range(1,6):
   return choiceanswer
  else:
    return Choice(question)


loop = True


 while loop:
    DisplayMenu()
    choiceanswer = Choice('Please make your choice:')
    if choiceanswer == 1:
      student = []
      n = numberofstudentstoadd('How many students do you wish to add? You 
 can add between 1 and 5')
      for count in range(0, n):
```

when I test this code the question for choice is reoccurring each time I put a number from the range in or it crashes/error message when I type text.

I need the program to run so that when I type 1-6 the number corresponds with the task I have asked it to do so for this instance 1 is to input student data. When text is input I need the question to reappear to make the user insert a number 1 to 6 based on the range. Hope this make better sense.

This is what is shown in the program:

```
MAIN MENU
1. Enter and store student details
2. Retrieve details of any student
3. Student List: Birthday Order
4. Student Email List
5. Full Student List
6. Exit
Please make your choice:e
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\BCS\From desktop\Validation 3\tutor.py", line 84, in <module>
        choiceanswer = Choice('Please make your choice:')
      File "E:\BCS\From desktop\Validation 3\tutor.py", line 72, in Choice
        choiceanswer=int(input(question))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'
```

Comment: you have `choiceddanswer` and `choiceanswer`, is it a typo?

Comment: thanks for that hahah I have altered that. But now it doesnt recognise the number is for a command:

Comment: def Choice(question):
  choiceanswer=input(question)
  if choiceanswer in range(1,6):
    return choiceanswer
  else:
    return Choice(question)

  
loop = True
   
  
while loop:
    DisplayMenu()
    choiceanswer = Choice('Please make your choice:')
    if choiceanswer == 1:
      student = []
      n = numberofstudentstoadd('How many students do you wish to add? You can add between 1 and 5')

Comment: thanks ive edited it. New to this site!!

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

### *question for choice is reoccurring each time I put a number from the range*

Well of course, you are not setting the *loop* variable to *False* anywhere, so the *while* condition is always positive.

### *it crashes/error message when I type text*

That's because `input` function evaluates input as Python code. When you enter *SER*, it doesn't mean a string `"SER"`, but a variable `SER` – and you end up with *NameError*.

You should use `raw_input` instead. Besides being the reason for your error, the `input` function is also quite dangerous. And actually, in Python 3, *input* is replaced with *raw_input*.

### solution

Your code could look like this

```
def choose(question):
    choiceanswer = raw_input(question)

    if choiceanswer == 'SER':
        global loop
        loop = False
        return

    if int(choiceanswer) in range(1, 6):
        return choiceanswer
    else:
        return choose(question)

loop = True

while loop:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. SER is just random text i was using to test that the program will run without crashing/error message.